# Connect to WiFi Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

Okay, got Ubuntu 18.04 for a server. I get that ethernet is optimal, but I don't have access to it where I'm at. There is literally no option to get wireless connecting software on it, without getting it through the internet. What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

In a server, without a desktop environment, you are expected to manually configure networking. In Ununtu 18.04 and later, this is accomplished in netplan.

**Step 1**: Determine if you have a wireless device that has a working driver. Run the command:

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
```

Ideally, you will see something like:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b2] (rev 83)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 [8086:c270]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

If there is no entry for 'Kernel driver in use' then you will need to install a driver and, possibly, firmware. Use the pci.id, in my example 8086:08b2, and search Ask Ubuntu for details as to how to find and install the driver.

NOTE: This assumes that yours is an internal, that is, PCI wireless device. If yours is a USB wireless device, I will amend my answer to suit.

**Step 2**: If you have identified your wireless device and know that it has a working driver, find its interface name. Run the command:

```
iwconfig
```

You will see something like:

```
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on
```

In this example, the interface name is wlp3s0. We will need that in the next steps.

**Step 3**: Amend the netplan file. Find out which you have with:

```
ls /etc/netplan
```

I suspect you will have either 01-netcfg.yaml or else 50-cloud-init.yaml. If yours is 50-cloud-init.yaml and your server is NOT intended to be a cloud instance, then you will need to disable cloud-init. Run the command:

```
sudo -i
echo "network: {config: disabled}"  >>  /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg
exit
```

This previous step is not needed if you have 01-netcfg.yaml.

Now edit your netplan file:

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/XXX.yaml
```

...where XXX represents the actual name of the file you found above.

Amend the file to something like:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlp3s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.0.21/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.0.1, 8.8.8.8]
      access-points:
        "network_ssid_name":
          password: "**********"
```

Please note that the network SSID name and the password are enclosed in quotes. Netplan is specific about indentation, spacing, etc. Please proofread twice. Save and exit nano.

Of course, susbstitute your exact details here.

Example netplan files are found in /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples.

Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Reboot and check:

```
iwconfig
```

If you are connected, you will see the interface is associated with the name of the network:

```
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"mylilrouter"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.745 GHz  Access Point: A4:2B:B0:DC:45:85   
      Bit Rate=866.7 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on
      Link Quality=60/70  Signal level=-50 dBm
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :), however, I get a not found error for iwconfig

Comment: How about: `ip addr show`?

Comment: I'll check back tommorow